# Latex sideways figure match page size

Tags: latex

I have sideways table that is slightly too large. I want it to make it smaller that it fits on the page. I tried \small \resizebox, nothing works. Any idea how it could work? Please find below the table.

I have sideways table that is slightly too large. I want it to make it smaller that it fits on the page. I tried \small \resizebox, nothing works. Any idea how it could work? Please find below the table.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{FB01}{fi}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{FB02}{fl}
%\usepackage[space]{grffile}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[paper=portrait,pagesize]{typearea}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{float, afterpage, rotating, graphicx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{multirow, booktabs, makecell, caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\small
  \caption{Portfolio return and risk performance}
  \label{pfperformance}
  \begin{threeparttable}
  \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{10}{c}}
    \toprule

    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Sample covariance matrix} &   & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Shrinkage covariance matrix}  \\

 \cmidrule{2-5}    \cmidrule(l{1cm}){6-10}  


          & HRP & IV & MV & MD & & HRP & IV & MV & MD \\

\midrule
Pandel A: Window = 250 &  &  &  & \\
\midrule
    Annualized return & 2.8913 & 2.6522 & 2.3518 & 4.5343 & & 3.4178 & 2.6522 & 2.3515 & 3.4646 \\
    Annualized volatility & 0.8819 & 0.8779 & 1.4456 & 2.8673 & & 0.9805 & 0.8779 & 1.0602 & 1.5449 \\
    Value-at-Risk (5\%)   & 0.0098 & 0.0005 & 0.0043 & 0.0130 & & 0.0135 & 0.0005 & 0.0010 & 0.0046 \\
    Conditional Value-at-Risk (5\%)  & 0.0019 & 0.0011 & 0.0005 & 0.0019 & & 0.0049 & 0.0011 & 0.0004 & 0.0019 \\
    Drawdown    & 0.3171 & 0.3540 & 0.7069 & 0.8459 & & 0.3817 & 0.3540 & 0.5822 & 0.7181 \\
    Maximum drawdown   & 0.4435 & 0.4389 & 0.7755 & 0.8834 & & 0.5152 & 0.4389 & 0.6920 & 0.7917 \\
    Sharpe ratio    & 0.1716 & 0.1581 & 0.0852 & 0.0828 & & 0.1825 &  0.1581 & 0.1161 & 0.1174 \\
    Calmar ratio    & 6.5185 & 6.0423 & 3.0326 & 5.1325 & & 6.6337 &  6.0423  & 3.3983 & 4.3760 \\
    Sortino ratio   & 0.0072 & 0.0066 & 0.0068 & 0.0121 & & 0.0081 & 0.0066 & 0.0063 & 0.0092 \\

    \midrule
Panel B: Window = 500 &  &  &  & \\
\midrule
    Annualized return & 2.9839 & 2.7675 & 2.2262 & 4.7684 & & 3.4379 & 2.7675 & 2.2100 & 3.6598 \\
    Annualized volatility & 0.9310 & 0.9295 & 0.9744 & 2.6048 & & 1.0319 & 0.9295 & 0.8484 & 1.5313 \\
    Value-at-Risk (5\%)   & 0.0175 & 0.0182 & 0.0160 & 0.0229 & & 0.0039 & 0.0182 & 0.0269 & 0.0215\\
    Conditional Value-at-Risk (5\%)  & 0.0132 & 0.0116 & 0.0081 & 0.0131 & & 0.0130 & 0.0116 & 0.0099 & 0.0125\\
    Drawdown    & 0.3171 & 0.3539 & 0.4944 & 0.8169 & & 0.3817 & 0.3539 & 0.2857 & 0.6883\\
    Maximum drawdown   & 0.4435 & 0.4389 & 0.6134 & 0.8611 & & 0.5152 & 0.4389 & 0.4251 & 0.7714\\
    Sharpe ratio    & 0.1677 & 0.1558 & 0.1195 & 0.0958 & & 0.1744 & 0.1558 & 0.1363 & 0.1251\\
    Calmar ratio    & 6.7275 & 6.3050 & 3.6293 & 5.5371 & & 6.6729 & 6.3050 & 5.1982 & 4.7444\\
    Sortino ratio   & 0.0077 & 0.0071 & 0.0066 & 0.0130 & & 0.0084 & 0.0071  & 0.0060 & 0.0098\\

    \midrule
Panel C: Window = 750 &  &  &  & \\
\midrule
    Annualized return & 2.9737 & 2.8767 & 2.2161 & 5.5427 & & 3.4330 & 2.8767 & 2.7677 & 3.9270 \\
    Annualized volatility & 0.9832 & 1.0010 & 0.9142 & 2.7918 & & 1.0737 & 1.0010 & 1.2177 & 1.6674 \\
    Value-at-Risk (5\%)   & 0.0650 & 0.0596 & 0.0804 & 0.0793 & & 0.0546 & 0.0596 & 0.0684 & 0.0706 \\
    Conditional Value-at-Risk (5\%)  & 0.0077 & 0.0060 & 0.0048 & 0.0095 & & 0.0062 & 0.0060 & 0.0057 & 0.0074 \\
    Drawdown    & 0.3171 & 0.3539 & 0.3213 & 0.8069 & & 0.3817 & 0.3539 & 0.5395 & 0.6784 \\
    Maximum drawdown   & 0.4059 & 0.4389 & 0.4792 & 0.8525 & & 0.4719 & 0.4389 & 0.6651 & 0.7633 \\
    Sharpe ratio    & 0.1583 & 0.1504 & 0.1268 & 0.1039 & & 0.1674 & 0.1504 & 0.1190 & 0.1233 \\
    Calmar ratio    & 7.3246 & 6.5537 & 4.6244 & 6.5014 & & 7.2750 & 6.5537 & 4.1616 & 5.1448 \\
    Sortino ratio   & 0.0079 & 0.0076 & 0.0067 & 0.0153 & & 0.0087 & 0.0076 & 0.0076 & 0.0106 \\

  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular*}
  \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
  \footnotesize
  \item\hspace{-2.5pt}\noindent\textit{Note:} The table presents portfolio performance and risk statistics using rolling-window sample and shrinkage covariance matrix estimates of 250, 500, and 750 days. The shrinkage covariance matrix is calculated following \cite{ledoit2004honey}, where the shrinkage target $S$ is a diagonal matrix of only variances with zeros elsewhere and the shrinkage constant is $\delta=0.3$. We use an annualization factor of 250 trading days. All series are in logarithmic first differences.
  \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should use the adjustbox package which is the best and more flexible way to resize (among many other features) a box in LaTeX.

Just add

```
\usepackage{adjustbox}
```

in your pramble.

And enclose the box you want to resize with an adjustbox environment

```
\begin{sidewaystable}
\small
  \caption{Portfolio return and risk performance}
  \label{pfperformance}
  \begin{adjustbox}{scale=0.95,center}
  \begin{threeparttable}
   ....
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

Just adapt the scale to your needs. You can also use

```
  \begin{adjustbox}{width=\texwidth,center}
```

Without center, your box will be flushed left (and hence downwards in the sideway table).